# Can you compile C for other operating systems?

Tags: c, mingw, gnu, multiplatform

I was just wondering, if there is a way, to compile my code, from my windows machine to other os, or do I have to setup everything for the compilation on VMs.
I have already changed up the code, so that it is possible to compile it on diffrent platforms, I'm just wondering if there is a way, to compile it for other operating systems in mingw, or in GNU. (If there is a way to do it in GNU, I'm fine with moving to linux, and compiling everything there)

Comment: It is possible to compile code for an OS other than the one the compiler is running on, with the right compiler.

Comment: Yes, but it's usually tricky to set up. It's easier to use VMs. The problem is that the compiler needs to know about the stuff that exists in the other OS, which means you either actually install that OS, or you have the header files from that OS telling the compiler which stuff is in the OS, and they could be out of date, or for the wrong version, and keeping them in sync is often annoying.

Comment: which OS is the other OS? Linux?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to reply to Scott.

Comment: it still matters what the other OS is. Generally you need a compiler for that OS, but the compiler itself needs to be compiled for the OS you are running, so that you can run it. This is called a cross-compiler. There's no reason it's impossible, it's just that most of the time it's a pain in the butt.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your help, I'll try find a cross compiler that works, and if not, I'll setup the VMs.
Thanks :DDD

Comment: The nice thing with VMs is that it takes very little time and effort to get it working. Adding a new target platform is often just a matter of pulling a new image down.

Comment: This is exactly what is done when programming for Arduino, so yes it is possible. But if you want to do it from Windows you may find it easier with LLVM/Clang than GCC, as it's not so easy to find cross compilers for many platforms that actually run on Windows. It's a lot easier from Linux. Or use CI tools like GitHub actions to build in the cloud (for example like here: https://github.com/brechtsanders/ci-test/actions)

Comment: That is exacly what I was looking for, thank you

Comment: Okay, I will change this to an answer so you can accept it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what is done when programming for Arduino, so yes it is possible.

But if you want to do it from Windows you may find it easier with LLVM/Clang than GCC, as it's not so easy to find cross compilers for many platforms that actually run on Windows.
It's a lot easier from Linux.

Or you can use CI tools like GitHub actions to build in the cloud.

I created an example project at https://github.com/brechtsanders/ci-test which uses GitHub actions (https://github.com/brechtsanders/ci-test/actions) to build on Ubuntu Linux, macOS and Windows.

You can use this project as the basis for a new cross-platform project.